# AS3: Find distance of rotation

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I am rotating an object with TweenLite, however instead of a set duration I want the duration to be based upon the distance of rotation where 180 degrees = 3 seconds 90 = 1.5 and so on.

Here is my attempt to find the distance of rotation:

```
var time:Number = Math.abs(Math.atan2(Math.sin(angle-wheelObj.rotation),Math.cos(angle-wheelObj.rotation)); 
TweenLite.to(wheelObj, time, {shortRotation:{rotation:angle}, ease:Expo.easeOut, onComplete:rotateWheel, onCompleteParams:[target]});
TweenLite.to(carObj, time, {shortRotation:{rotation:angle}, ease:Expo.easeOut});
```

This just isn't working, time is sometimes huge when the rotation is small and sometimes tiny when it is big, so does anyone know a better way to do this?

**Notes:**

`angle` = target rotation

`wheelObj.rotation` = current rotation.

Comment: i don't really get your first line - but why don't you just do a `var time = (angle-wheelObj.rotation)*timePerDegree`?

Comment: @pkyeck because angle can be greater or less than rotation (it uses negative angles and stuff too... very odd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var speed:Number = 60; // 3 sec for 180 deg
var time:Number = Math.abs(angle - wheelObj.rotation) / speed;
```

You can set duration by changing speed parameter.

Note: You might need to use angle as (angle%360)

Comment: Depending on where the current rotation is this is giving me 7 secs + for 10 - 20 degree rotations. or approx 0.3 seconds if I tween from the opposite side.

Comment: it should be opposite, 20 / 60 ~= 0.33 is right. and 340 / 60 ~= 5.66. Trace out your dest angle and current rotation. You might have problems with radian and degrees.

Comment: My angle is definetely in degrees and so is the rotation. alot of the angles are coming out correct, but about a third are wrong when testing it is to do with the fact that in a 20 degree span angle could = 0 and rotation 340 (20 degrees apart) which results in just under 6 seconds via that formula

Comment: if its still not working there is another thing. Movieclips rotation is between [-180,180].

Comment: I have converted the rotation to be between 0 and 360 via this line `var endAngle:Number = (wheelObj.rotation < 0) ? 360 + wheelObj.rotation : wheelObj.rotation;` and started using the endangle instead of rotation and it still doesnt work because 1 degree after 360 is 0 which messes up the numbers when we use a value ether side of it.

Comment: your tweener finds the shortest rotation side, you have to find it too. Like tagetAngle = 340 and currentAngle = 20, your diffrence have to be 40. and the time is 40/60=0.66

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong (I've not used this library), but it seems you are overcomplicating this. You should just do:

```
θ=W*t
```

Where you W is:

```
W=2*pi/6
```

So you have:

```
θ=pi*t/3 (rads) or
θ=60*t (degrees)
```

**Revision**: For the shortest angle,

```
t= |θ| / 60 for θ < 180
t= ( 180 - |θ| ) / 60 for θ > 180
```

Or in your case:

```
var speed:Number = 60;
var angle:Number = Math.abs(angle - wheelObj.rotation) % 360;
if (angle > 180 ) {
     angle = 180 - angle;
}
var time:Number = Math.abs(angle)/speed;
```

Comment: sorry can you tell me what `W` and `t` stand for.

Comment: Oh sorry W is Omega (the angle) and t is time. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_displacement)

Answer (score 0):

The solution if anyone is interested:

```
var rotationSpeed:Number = 60;
var startAngle:Number = (angle < 0) ? (angle + 360) % 360:angle % 360;
var endAngle:Number = (wheelObj.rotation < 0) ? (wheelObj.rotation + 360) % 360:wheelObj.rotation % 360;
var distance:Number = (Math.max(startAngle,endAngle) - Math.min(startAngle,endAngle) > (360 + Math.min(startAngle,endAngle))- Math.max(startAngle,endAngle)) ? (360 + Math.min(startAngle,endAngle))- Math.max(startAngle,endAngle) : Math.max(startAngle,endAngle) - Math.min(startAngle,endAngle);
var time:Number = distance / rotationSpeed;
TweenLite.to(wheelObj, time, {shortRotation:{rotation:angle}, ease:Expo.easeOut, onComplete:rotateWheel, onCompleteParams:[target]});
TweenLite.to(carObj, time, {shortRotation:{rotation:angle}, ease:Expo.easeOut});
```

The following algorithm:

```
var distance:Number = (Math.max(startAngle,endAngle) - Math.min(startAngle,endAngle) > (360 + Math.min(startAngle,endAngle))- Math.max(startAngle,endAngle)) ? (360 + Math.min(startAngle,endAngle))- Math.max(startAngle,endAngle) : Math.max(startAngle,endAngle) - Math.min(startAngle,endAngle);
```

Compares the largest angle - the smallest angle to the smallest angle + 360 minus the largest angle and sees which one is bigger and sets itself as the answer. e.g,

20 and 320

320 - 20 = 300
(20 + 360) - 320 = 40

this works for any two angles (between 0 and 360) and always finds the shortest route.