# Using AS3, how can I make one object rotate towards a given target until it is just about facing that target?

Tags: actionscript-3, target, trigonometry, angle, direction

I never tried to learn trigonometry before I started trying to program and that is bound to show, but I don't think that this a is particularly easy thing to get your head around.  I'm trying to learn as much as I can, but right now, I have no maths in my brain and I would really appreciate help with this.  I don't just want to make one object face another, so much as I want an object to rotate towards a given target until it is just about facing that target.

```
if (target != null)
    {
        if (DistanceTwoPoints(xPos, yPos, target.x, target.y) < 312)
        {
            var direction:Number = (angle * (180 / Math.PI)) + 90;
            var targetDirection:Number = Math.atan2(yPos - target.y, xPos - target.x) * (180 / Math.PI);
            if (direction-10 > targetDirection) { RotateLeft();}
            else if (direction+10 < targetDirection) { RotateRight(); }
        }
    }
```

In my top down space game, the above code currently makes my enemies turn and face the player.  The obvious problem is that once the targetDirection moves past 0 or 360, the enemy rotates towards them **the long way around**.

I think that about covers the problem but I've never asked for help on a site like this before so if I've missed anything let me know.  I'll be keeping an eye out for responses.

Thanks very much.

**/* EDIT */**

Ok. Through a lot of semi-educated guesswork and some wild stabbing in the dark, I've eventually got it working perfectly... but I am going to hate the code until I know that there isn't a far better ways to do this. If anyone would like to suggest a better way I am very open to suggestions. Here is my current code.

```
if (target != null)
{
if (DistanceTwoPoints(xPos, yPos, target.x, target.y) < 312)
{
    if (angle * (180 / Math.PI) +90 > 180) { angle = angle - (360 / (180 / Math.PI));}
    if (angle * (180 / Math.PI) +90 < -180) { angle = angle + (360 / (180 / Math.PI));}
    var direction:Number = (angle * (180 / Math.PI)) +90;
    var targetDirection:Number = Math.atan2(yPos - target.y, xPos - target.x) * (180 / Math.PI);
    if (direction-targetDirection < -180 || direction-targetDirection > 180)
    {
        if (direction-2 > targetDirection) { RotateRight(); }
        else if (direction+2 < targetDirection) { RotateLeft(); }
    }
    else 
    {
        if (direction-2 > targetDirection) { RotateLeft();}
        else if (direction+2 < targetDirection) { RotateRight(); }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you out: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486040/as3-find-distance-of-rotation[/link]

Comment: The description of the solution posted by George Reith certainly feels like it should apply to what I'm trying to do.  I'll just have to sit and scratch my head at it for a while and see if I make any progress.  Thanks.